# Запрос к базе, вывод уникальных значений и их количество

Tags: php, mysql

Делаю запрос к бд: SELECT DISTINCT MODEL FROM advert WHERE COMPLETE=1
Выводится список моделей из таблицы объявлений, без повторений. 
А как в этом же запросе указать вывод количества объявлений в которых данные модели?
Пример:

Модель1 = 232 объявлений

Модель2 = 112 объявлений

Модель3 = 31 объявлений

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT model, COUNT(message) AS qty FROM Advert
WHERE complete = 1
GROUP BY model
```

Читайте агрегированные функции SQL